# Unable to Change Subscription Schedule in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

When I try to edit any subscription schedule I get the below error, it's not user permission issue because it was working before and nothing was changed on users permissions.

"Something went wrong. Please try again later."

Now, the only way now to edit the schedule is to change the time from the database which require more time.

Comment: Could you please post  complete log of Error.
Also just a basic step try Internet Explorer within the SQL Server itself (i.e. the localhost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [AnkUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5436880/ankuser)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604863/unable-to-change-subscription-schedule-in-ssrs/55611895#comment97906962_55604863):

> just a basic step try Internet Explorer within the SQL Server itself (i.e. the localhost).

works. I tried to use Internet Explorer instead of FireFox and it works fine.